# Creating AudioBuffers from MediaRecorder Chunks

Tags: javascript, typescript, audio, webrtc

I'm trying to analyse Audio in realtime as it flows in, using a function that takes an AudioBuffer. I convert the Blob that the recorder gives me with the following function, but it throws a `DOMException: Unable to decode audio data`.

```js
async function audioBufferFromBlob(blob: Blob, audioCtx: AudioContext): Promise<AudioBuffer> {
    return await audioCtx.decodeAudioData(await new Response(blob).arrayBuffer());
}
```

I believe this is due to the fact, that the recorders ondataavailable blobs aren't full audio streams only chunks. Is there a way convert the blobs to full audio streams?

Full code:

```js
import PitchFinder = require('pitchfinder');

const amdf = PitchFinder.AMDF();

function logPitch(pitch: [number, number], elem: HTMLElement) {
    elem.innerText = pitch.toString();
}

function detectPitch(audioBuffer: AudioBuffer): [number, number]{
    let frequency = amdf(audioBuffer.getChannelData(0));
    return [frequency, noteFromFrequency(frequency)]
}
async function audioBufferFromBlob(blob: Blob, audioCtx: AudioContext): Promise<AudioBuffer> {
    return await audioCtx.decodeAudioData(await new Response(blob).arrayBuffer());
}

function noteFromFrequency(frequency: number ): number {
    let noteNum = 12 * (Math.log( frequency / 440 )/Math.log(2) );
    return Math.round( noteNum ) + 69;
}

export function displayPitch(displayElem: HTMLElement) {
    let audioCtx = new AudioContext();
    navigator.getUserMedia({audio: true, video: false}, successCallback, errorCallback);

    function errorCallback() {
        alert("Something went wrong.");
    }
    function successCallback(stream: MediaStream) {
        let recorder = new MediaRecorder(stream, { mimeType: 'audio/webm'});
        recorder.ondataavailable = async (event: BlobEvent) => {
            let buffer = await audioBufferFromBlob(event.data, audioCtx);
            logPitch(detectPitch(buffer), displayElem);
        };
        recorder.start(500);
    }
}
```